# My windows powershell display weird chars

Tags: powershell, windows-10

My windows powershell display weird chars suddenly like the following:

[39;49m // [39;49mClearing the cache for the [32mdev[39m environment with debug [32mtrue[39m

Anyone knows what is the issue?

Comment: There is a leftarrow in front of every `[`, somehow this get lost when editing the question :(

Comment: Those look like ANSI console control codes. What does the script do? Can you wrap up a MCVE?

Comment: I am working on orocommerce platform and I did clear cache command. not just this command all of commands I did using powershell display weird chars.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like in the format of `bash`. I suppose a script has changed your command line to `bash` but does not change it back at the end.

Just type in

> exit

to quit `bash on PowerShell` and return to `PowerShell`.

---

If `bash` scripts are heavily used, I would recommend you start `bash` to run the scripts and view the output formatted correctly (hopefully), and type in

> PowerShell

to launch `PowerShell on bash` to run PowerShell commands.